# DateTime.Parse with custom formats

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to use `DateTime.Parse` in order to parse a string containing a `DateTime` in a custom format.

The format is `yy-MMM MMMM-dddd-ddd-dd`, the string is `15-jan. január-szerda-Sze-07`.

I've modified the `ShortDatePattern` in the OS' regional settings, and you can see it in the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` while debugging.

[image: Watch the pattern in debug]

I'm using the following code:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateInString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

But it fails with exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Using `ParseExact` it **does** work.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateInString, 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Shouldn't `Parse` work as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

Assuming `Parse` is just not good enough, should this be okay or can it cause problem I can't think of right now (it works with the aforementioned problem)?

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();

bool success = false;

foreach (var format in currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
    success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, culture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out date);

    if (success)
        break;
}

if (!success)
    throw new Exception();
```

Comment: I think your format is wrong. In form your have yy-mmm but in your input you have "15-jan." the '.' might be creating problem here,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Thanks for your comment, but Hungarian abbreviated months end with a `.`. Also please notice that the `ParseExact` works

Comment: What is your FullDateTimeFormat? Are Short and Full format same? If no then I guess Parse method uses FullFormat instead of ShortFormat,

Comment: Only the `ShortDatePattern` looks like that, but I believe that's supposed to be enough. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Parse2_Example) says: `For the conversion, uses the formatting conventions of a specified culture and interprets the string based on the DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces style flag (example).`

Comment: That's strange. Use TryParse method. And see if that works or not,

Comment: `TryParse` returns false.

Comment: If you remove '.' and then use TryParse or Parse, does it work?

Comment: Nope, and there's no reason it would work, because the abbreviated month names contain the dot (that's how the this string was created to begin with)..

Comment: I added actual code of Parse method in answer. Have a look, and see if that can help.

Comment: Trouble with DateTime? Check out Jon Skeet's NodaTime: https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Comment: As I said in the post, `ParseExact` works

Answer (score 4):

I played a little bit with your example and I couldn't make it work. I think that *DateTime.Parse* is simply not clever enough to parse your string and MSDN documentation confirms that. Here is a section from [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ey1cdcx8(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation according to which *Parse* should not be used with custom cultures/patterns and why:

> *If you parse a date and time string generated for a custom culture, use the ParseExact method instead of the Parse method to improve the
>   probability that the parse operation will succeed. A custom culture
>   date and time string can be complicated, and therefore difficult to
>   parse. The Parse method attempts to parse a string with several
>   implicit parse patterns, all of which might fail.*

And here is another interesting fragment from [SetAllDateTimePatterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.setalldatetimepatterns(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> *The Parse and TryParse methods do not fully iterate all strings in patterns when parsing the string representation of a date and time. If
>   you require a date and time string to have particular formats in a
>   parsing operation, you should pass the array of valid formats to the
>   DateTime.ParseExact...*

Comment: Thank you, please see my edit for a question about a possible solution

Comment: `+1` because this is the most logical opinion/fact so far about this problem. All string parts _exactly_ matches with `yy-MMM MMMM-dddd-ddd-dd` format based on `hu-HU` culture values. `DateTime.Parse` method _might_ even confuse to parse `jan.` with `MMM` since `.` is a `DateSeparator` of `hu-HU` culture. I don't know..